# GoogleLocationService problema de obter latitude e longitude

Tags: c#, google-maps

Segue o código:

**Tentativa 1:(Funciona)**

```
var address = "Osasco - SP, Brasil";
var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();
var point = locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(address);
```

**Tentativa 2: (Não funciona)**

```
var address = "uol - Rua dos Autonomistas - Santa Paula, São Caetano do Sul - SP, Brasil";
var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();
var point = locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(address);
```

Porque na segunda tentativa, o variável point é nulo ? Variável point nulo não consigo obter lat e long.

Já tentei obter lat e long através desse [site](http://www.latlong.net/). Mesma assim não funciona com esse nome :

> uol - Rua dos Autonomistas - Santa Paula, São Caetano do Sul - SP,
>   Brasil

Pelo google maps official ele acha com lat e long: https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/uol/@-23.6146064,-46.5673915,21z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x94ceff43154a6537:0x90bb93302710c14d!8m2!3d-23.6145972!4d-46.5672306?hl=pt-BR

Alguma solução brilhante ?

Comment: Depende do formato do resto dos dados. Se for sempre um pedaço que não faz parte do endereço no começo, só descartar.

Comment: Vc terá que olhar na documentação do GoogleLocationService. Quais as condições para o método `locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(string)` retorna nulo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A API não encontra nada pois o address que você está passando é "inválido".

Seu address está inválido aos parâmetros pedidos pois você está passando uma parte que não faz parte do endereço, que é **uol -**. Essa parte é o local que você deseja (creio eu), mas não é um endereço para a API do google.

Pelo Google Maps ele localiza pois o sistema possui uma inteligência maior, por assim dizer, do que a própria API. 
Se você [pesquisar o endereço completo no google](https://www.google.com/search?q=uol%20-%20Rua%20dos%20Autonomistas%20-%20Santa%20Paula%2C%20S%C3%A3o%20Caetano%20do%20Sul%20-%20SP%2C%20Brasil&oq=uol%20-%20Rua%20dos%20Autonomistas%20-%20Santa%20Paula%2C%20S%C3%A3o%20Caetano%20do%20Sul%20-%20SP%2C%20Brasil&aqs=chrome..69i57.475j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), verá que você encontra uma empresa cadastrada, e com isso o endereço é válido. Para a API, buscando por endereço, não é.

[Veja este exemplo buscando com **uol -**.](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=uol%20-%20Rua%20dos%20Autonomistas%20-%20Santa%20Paula,%20S%C3%A3o%20Caetano%20do%20Sul%20-%20SP,%20Brasil)

Nesse exemplo o resultado é:

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

[Agora, se você remover apenas o **uol -**](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Rua%20dos%20Autonomistas%20-%20Santa%20Paula,%20S%C3%A3o%20Caetano%20do%20Sul%20-%20SP,%20Brasil), verá o seguinte resultado:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Rua dos Autonomistas",
               "short_name" : "R. dos Autonomistas",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Paula",
               "short_name" : "Santa Paula",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "São Caetano do Sul",
               "short_name" : "São Caetano do Sul",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "São Paulo",
               "short_name" : "SP",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brasil",
               "short_name" : "BR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "09520-040",
               "short_name" : "09520-040",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "R. dos Autonomistas - Santa Paula, São Caetano do Sul - SP, 09520-040, Brasil",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -23.6134371,
                  "lng" : -46.5672122
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -23.6152546,
                  "lng" : -46.5674237
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -23.6145817,
               "lng" : -46.5673196
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -23.6129968697085,
                  "lng" : -46.5659689697085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -23.6156948302915,
                  "lng" : -46.5686669302915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJD0gD3e5czpQRQnEjTXrZaPE",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Note que no final o google até retornou um **place_id**, que é:

```
"place_id" : "ChIJD0gD3e5czpQRQnEjTXrZaPE",
```

Se você utilizar o [Reverse Geocoding by Place ID](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-place-id), verá o local exatato referente à ele, e me parece que é o local que está procurando.

Me corrija se eu estiver errado, mas acho que está utiliza o pacote [GoogleMaps.LocationServices](https://github.com/sethwebster/GoogleMaps.LocationServices).

Ele funciona para algumas coisas, mas acho que para seu caso não irá te atender perfeitamente. Você pode ver se o [pacote de API da própria Google](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/) lhe atende, ou você pode [procurar uma nova no Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=google%20maps%20api) e quem sabe, fazer a sua própria ou utilizar um simples WebCliente para retornar o JSON do navegador, desta forma:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    var address = "Rua dos Autonomistas - Santa Paula, São Caetano do Sul - SP, Brasil";
    var url = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}", address);
    var result = client.DownloadString(url);
}
```